# How can I display one object at a time?

Tags: opengl

I want to draw two objects and when I press a button to show only one. And when I press again to show the next one.

```
GLUquadricObj *newQuad = gluNewQuadric();
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glLoadIdentity ();
glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
glRotatef(50,1,0,0);

glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-200,80,0);
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(newQuad,GLU_LINE);
gluSphere(newQuad,30,30,10);
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(-130, 80, 0.0);
gluQuadricDrawStyle(newQuad,GLU_LINE);
gluCylinder( newQuad,20,20,60,20,10);
glPopMatrix();                      //cylinder

glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(-60, 80, 0);
gluQuadricDrawStyle(newQuad,GLU_LINE);
gluCylinder(newQuad,20,0,60,20,10);   //cone
glPopMatrix();
```

this is C++

Comment: Explain what you tried, what's your specific difficulty.

Comment: If you show code, you should tag the language (helps people find the question and also affects syntax highlighting). Is this C or C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a boolean variable and set it to `true` when you want one object to be displayed. When input happens flip the variable from `true` to `false` and vice versa.

```
//Variable
boolean showOneObject;

//Constructor
public MyClass()
{
    //...
    showOneObject = false;
}

//Inside input
public void input()
{
    //Flip variable
    showOneObject = !showOneObject;
}
```

Now when you are drawing do this

```
//If showOneObject == false, draw first object, otherwise only the second one
if (!showOneObject)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-130, 80, 0.0);
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(newQuad,GLU_LINE);
    gluCylinder( newQuad,20,20,60,20,10);
    glPopMatrix();     //cylinder
}                 

glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(-60, 80, 0);
gluQuadricDrawStyle(newQuad,GLU_LINE);
gluCylinder(newQuad,20,0,60,20,10);   //cone
glPopMatrix();
```